# Emploi de “y” en place des pronoms impersonnels : parler lyonnais, ou plus large?

Tags: régionalismes

L'une des caractéristiques du [parler lyonnais](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parler_lyonnais) est l'utilisation de ***y*** en place des pronoms impersonnels:

> - *Je vais y faire avant demain* [vs. “le faire”]
> - *Il y a donné dix coups de bâton* [vs. “lui a donné” ou “leur a donné”]

C'est typique d'une bonne partie du Dauphiné également (de Grenoble à Valence au moins), et j'ai rencontré cet été des hauts-savoyards qui confirment que c'est le cas chez eux également.

Ma question est : quelqu'un sait-il quelles sont les frontières (forcément vagues, bien sûr) de ce trait de language ? Si non, pouvez-vous donner en commentaire les infos que vous avez (“ah oui, je l'ai entendu ici et pas là”) ?

Comment: Jamais entendu (Belgique)

Comment: Pour ma part : je n'ai entendu cette construction ni à Paris, ni à Strasbourg, ni à Montpellier.

Comment: Il y a un tel mélange de culture qui fait que certaines expressions se retouvent au quatre coins de la France. En Beauce j'ai déjà entendu "j'va y faire pour demain".

Comment: Je confirme l'emploi courant en Savoie et Haute-Savoie

Comment: Une proposition a été faite (la réponse de snowflake) mais j'aimerais soit une référence, soit plus de données. Pour l'instant, je ne suis qu'à moitié convaincu. Donc, **bounty time!**

Comment: Je pratique personnellement le "Il y a mangé son goûter" et pourtant chez moi c'est l'extrême Sud-Est (de la France, même si je ne suis pas en France ;))

Comment: Et dans les Ardennes également je crois.

Comment: J'avoue que j'ai du mal à bien comprendre les détails de la question. En tant que complement impersonnel "y" s'utilise couramment (J'y ai pensé, j'y ai fait gaffe, etc...) et il ne s'agit pas d'un régionalisme. Bien sûr, dans la question on fait référence à une autre usage; peut-être il s'agit de l'emploi de "y" en tant que complément d'objet disjoint ou conjoint? Le TLF dit que "y" peut être employé en tant qu'objet indirect lorsque les pron. conj. sont exclus, et que l'usage comme datif conj. est fam. Bref, tout ça pour dire que je ne comprends pas trop...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

L'aire géographique dans laquelle sont remplacés les pronoms impersonnels (mais également personnels, "Y faut le faire" pour "Il faut le faire") par "y", ressemble trait pour trait, à l'aire géographique du [francoprovençal](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francoproven%C3%A7al) (ou arpitan ou romand), langue dans laquelle le pronom "il" [se prononce "i"](http://fr.wikiversity.org/wiki/Pronoms_personnels/Arpitan) devant les consonnes.

L'aire serait donc Mâcon-Neuchatelle-Sion-Aoste-Grenoble-Saint Etienne-Lyon-Mâcon

Il serait intéressant de savoir si ce type d'erreur de langage que l'on retrouve en français, se retrouve également dans le Val d'Aoste (très francophone) en italien, et si cet emploi se retrouve dans des langues d'Oil plus au sud de Valence en France.

Comment: J’ai la vague impression que c’est plus large que ça, donc je suis toujours preneur de “points de données” supplémentaires !

Comment: Je peux attester dans la région de Chalon-sur-Saône, et au moins au nord jusqu'à Autun.

Comment: C'est même pire que tu le décris, en Bourgogne, ils disent plutôt *faut y faire*.

Comment: Il me semble avoir déjà entendu quelque chose comme "Je sais pas y faire" ici en Suisse romande.

Comment: En tant qu'italien, je peux confirmer que l'emploi du "ci" (qui est notre "y") est utilisé, des fois, pour remplacer des pronoms personnels comme dans "Ci ho detto di tacere" (Je lui ai dit de se taire) ou "Ci ho dato una lezione" (Je lui ai donné une leçon, dans le sens violent d'avoir frappé quelqu'un) ou encore "Ci ho spiegato la strada" (Je lui ai expliqué la route). Une particularité de l'italien est que "ci" est aussi le pron. pers. conjoint complément de la première personne du pluriel, comme "nous": "Ci ha regalato una torta" signifie "Il nous a offert une tarte".

Answer (score 4):

Attention : le y en Savoie remplace un COD (j'y mange = je LE mange, j'y dis, je LE dis), alors qu'ailleurs, les "y" remplacent des COI : j'y dis = je lui dis ; j'y pense = je pense à ça.

Une jolie cartographie est disponible sur ce site : https://francaisdenosregions.com/2016/09/01/le-y-dit-savoyard-laisse-je-vais-y-faire-y-manger-y-prendre/

Answer (score 2):

Cette façon de parler me paraît ressembler à celle que j'ai connue dans le Nord de la France (picard). Sur le plan phonétique tout du moins, parce que la construction, et l'écriture qui en découle, peut différer selon les cas :

```
J'y ai dit d'se taire. (Je lui ai dit de se taire)
```

En général, on remplace les "moi", "toi" et "lui" par "mi", "ti" et "li", ce qui donne juste le son "i" (qu'on écrit parfois "y") lorsqu'il y a une élision.

Quant à La forme "y faire", je la connais principalement dans l'expression "savoir y faire", dont je ne situe pas l'origine géographique.

Answer (score 2):

Cette manière de parler est également très utilisée au Québec.

Comment: "utilité" tu voudrais pas plutôt dire "usité" ou "commune"?

Comment: La deuxième variante est entendue au Québec, mais la première phrase serait plutôt élidée `Je vais l'faire avant demain`. Il ne s'agit pas de la même chose

Answer (score 1):

Je ne connaissais pas cette construction, intéressant.

Mais je remarque qu'en Bretagne ou en région parisienne, on peut très bien dire familièrement *"Mets-y un coup"* par exemple, qui a une construction similaire à l'exemple *"Il y a donné dix coups de bâton"*.

Answer (score 0):

En Bourgogne aussi pardi ! En tout cas à Beaune ;)

Answer (score 0):

Très utilisé à Clermont Ferrand aussi !

> "J'y fais demain" = je le fais demain
> "Fais y voir "  = montre moi ça
> "T'y mets dans la poêle puis t'y retournes" avec une spatule"= tu le mets dans la poêle puis tu le retournes de l'autre côté...

J'y dis, j'y vais, j'y vais, y'a qu'à....on le colle un peu partout