# Utilisation de « y » avec « atteindre »

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, prépositions

Dans une phrase

> Je veux atteindre Paris dans quelques heures.

est-ce que je peux remplacer 'Paris' par le pronom 'y' ? Dans la première phrase il n'y a pas de préposition 'à' pour utiliser 'y'

> Je veux y atteindre dans quelques heures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dans la grande majorité des dialectes, "y" ne peut avoir comme antécédent que des groupes ou des propositions introduites par les prépositions "à", "en", et quelques autres prépositions à sens locatif (*chez*, *dans*, etc.). Ce n'est pas le cas ici, puisqu'"atteindre" demande un complément d’objet direct, le pronom attendu étant donc:

> Je veux **l'**atteindre dans quelques heures

Cependant, dans les régions avec un substrat [franco-provençal](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francoproven%C3%A7al) (Suisse, Savoie, Lyonnais, Franche-Comté, Val d'Aoste, etc.) , "y" a été emprunté (en plus de ses usages habituels) comme pronom objet direct neutre. (L'arpitan faisant la différence entre le masculin, le féminin et le neutre dans les pronoms clitiques sujets et objets directs)

Dans ces dialectes, il est donc tout a fait possible d'utiliser "y" pour se référer à un objet direct inanimé ou abstrait, comme "Paris".

> Je veux y atteindre dans quelques heures.

Est donc correct localement, mais pas partout (et pas dans tous les registres de langue, c'est largement un fait de la langue parlée)

---

Un peu plus de lecture :

DAGNAC Anne, [La variation régionale des proformes faibles en français](https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00988601/document)  document préparatoire pour contribution à la Grande Grammaire du français (Abeillé, A., Godard, G..  2012)

AVANZI Matthieu, [Le « y » dit savoyard : laissez-moi vous y expliquer !](https://francaisdenosregions.com/2015/09/11/le-y-dit-savoyard-laisse-je-vais-y-faire-y-manger-y-prendre/), du très excellent blog [Français de nos régions](https://francaisdenosregions.com/).

On avait déjà parlé du phénomène sur FL par le passé : [Emploi de “y” en place des pronoms impersonnels : parler lyonnais, ou plus large?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/255/emploi-de-y-en-place-des-pronoms-impersonnels-parler-lyonnais-ou-plus-large/263)

Answer (score 1):

On dirait plutôt "je veux l'atteindre dans quelques heures".

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour,

Oui tu peux remplacer 'Paris' par 'y' mais dans ce cas tu dois changer atteindre par autre chose. Je ne sais pas vraiment quelle est la règle derrière cela mais tu devra dire :

> Je veux y aller dans quelques heures.